# Ember Data v1 beta issue with store.find()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get a app to work using the ember data 1.0 beta release and having issues getting the route to trigger a find the associated models loaded from a server.

Here's what my objects look like:

```
App.Technician = DS.Model.extend({
  first_name: DS.attr(),
  last_name: DS.attr(),
  name: function(){
    return this.get('first_name')+' '+this.get('last_name');
  }.property('first_name', 'last_name')
});

App.TechniciansRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('technician');
  }
});
```

However when the technicians route tries to load the model the this.get('store').find() always throws an exception that find is not defined.
I've debugged into it and hit the following function

```
store: Ember.computed(function(){
    var container = this.container;
    var routeName = this.routeName;
    var namespace = get(this, 'router.namespace');

    return {
      find: function(name, value) {
        var modelClass = container.lookupFactory('model:' + name);

        Ember.assert("You used the dynamic segment " + name + "_id in your route "+ routeName + ", but " + namespace + "." + classify(name) + " did not exist and you did not override your route's `model` hook.", modelClass);

        return modelClass.find(value);
      }
    };
  })
```

modelClass is an reference to App.Technician which does not have find() defined on it, and hence the execption is throw.

Does anyone have any ideas? it feels like I'm missing something simple but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intuitivepixel lead me down the right path but basically what was happening was a dependency loading issue.

I am using require.js to load my dependencies and what was happening is I didn't have ember-data as a dependency before my Application.create was being called. This caused the Application.initializers to never be triggered on the application objects I was creating as the initializes were not added untill my data models and routes were being loaded.

so long story short. Makes sure ember-data is loaded before calling Ember.Application.create();

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `this.store.find(...)` instead of `this.get('store').find(...)`:

```
App.TechniciansRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('technician');
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting, this.store is undefined but this.get('store') returns an object. Does this mean that ember data isn't properly filling out the store on my route? It would make sense why I'm having issues.

Comment: @Richard, normally ember injects the store in every route at app start, but all guides I've seen after the transition to 1.0.0 suggest using `this.store` instead of `this.get('store')` I guess you already read this: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md in every example `this.store` is used